# Laravel Call to a member function follows() on a non-object issue

Tags: laravel, symfony, laravel-5, laravel-4, laravel-5.1

My UserController includes the following:

```
public function doaction($domain, $some_id)
{
  $user = User::find(Sentry::getUser()->id);
  $user->doactions()->attach($some_id);
  $response = array('message' => 'doactioned', 'url' => 'http://'.$domain.'.'.Config::get('database.domain').'/undoaction/'.$some_id);
  return Response::json($response);
}
```

My routes.php includes also the following line:

```
Route::get('/{name}/doaction/{some_id}', array('as' => 'doaction', 'uses' => 'UserController@doaction'));
```

I am trying to call this front he frontend:

```
<a href="{{URL::route('doaction', array('domain' => $blog->name, 'id' => $blog->id))}}" class="tumblerclone-btn"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Do action here </a>
```

And once its pressed (the URL is echoed properly), it leads me to an error:

**Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Call to a member function doactions() on a non-object**

The highlighted code part of the error is:

```
public function doaction($domain, $some_id)
{
  $user = User::find(Sentry::getUser()->id);
  $user->doactions()->attach($some_id);
  $response = array('message' => 'doactioned', 'url' => 'http://'.$domain.'.'.Config::get('database.domain').'/undoaction/'.$some_id);
  return Response::json($response);
}
```

Any ideas are appreciated in advance.

Comment: Your user is null, you need to check if it finds any user with that id

Comment: Check what are you getting in ```Sentry::getUser()->id``` and ```dd($user)```

Comment: After getting `$user` at line 1, you must check that user already found or not. In this case user not found and returns `null` and no any `null` has `doactions()` method.